# THREE JS DefaultLoadingManager onProgress function returns wrong number of total items first

Tags: three.js, loading

I used this code to calculate the percentage of loading:

```
THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.onProgress = (item, loaded, total) => {
        console.error(loaded / total * 100);
};
```

It reaches about 80% and then returns to 60% then it reaches 90% and then returns to 80%.

After some debugging, I found that the number of total items first is 25 and then increases to about 35 and after that, it reaches 52.

This increase is because of JSONLoader. I load some objects and these objects have materials as images, so onProgress function adds these images to the total number of items to be loaded.

I want to know how to know the real number of items to be loaded (52) at the start. If it is not possible, how to solve the going-back from 80% to 60%?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things you could do:

You can run your load once, and record the results the final count, and hardcode it for the next run.

or..

Use a format like GLTF with all the assets embedded. Then you'll get one item per model.

or..
Fire off all your loads in parallel.. don't respond to the first few onProgress.. and hopefully capture the complete item count before you start displaying progress..

or.. make a progress bar that always advances by some percentage of the remaining time, and maybe adjust that percentage to roughly match the load time on your single machine, or adjust it dynamically as you get more information about remaining loads.

Comment: 1- I tried it and it worked but it is my last solution. 2- I didn't understand this. 3- I am doing it in parallel, but the models that have image-materials (that increases the number of total items) are too heavy and needs a long time to load while others are loaded in moments. 4- I can't do this because the size of my site is about 15 MB and it depends on internet connection speed, but this solution help me to figure out a new solution: I will make the progress bar keep the large percentage (80% in my case) and don't get new percentage except it is more than 80%